# Level Order Traversal of BST in Java

Tags: java, binary-search-tree, breadth-first-search

I'm trying to do a level order traversal on the following BST.

```
BST bst = new BST();
    int [] arr = {12, 15, 7, 3,  81, 9, 36, 23, 33, 41, 4};
    for (int i = 0; i <arr.length; i++) {
        bst.add(arr[i]);
    }
```

This is my code.

```
public static void levelOrderTraversal(Node root){
        if(root == null) return;
        Queue<Node> queue = new ArrayDeque<Node>();
        queue.add(root);
        while(!queue.isEmpty()){
            Node current = queue.peek();
            System.out.print(current.getData() + " ");
            if (current.left != null)
                queue.add(current.left);
            if (current.right != null){
                queue.add(current.right);
            }
            queue.poll();
        }
    }
```

The output that I get is

```
12 7 15 3 9 81 4 36 23 41 33
```

This clearly is not the correct BFS. Where am I going wrong.

Comment: The output looks like the correct BFS to me. Wanna a picture?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your traversal function is correct. You may want to check this online tool

https://www.cs.usfca.edu/~galles/visualization/BST.html

It provides visualization of the insert, delete and find process as well. This is the resulting tree:

[image]

Answer (score 1):

I don't see why, given the list of elements you provide the tree will look like:

```
12
 |- 7 (L)
    |- 3 (L)
        |- 4 (R)
    |- 9 (R)
 |- 15 (R)
    |- 81 (R)
        |- 36 (L)
            |- 23 (L)
                |- 33 (R)
            |- 41 (R)
```

Or a better visual:

```
    12
   /  \
  7    15
 / \     \
3   9     81
 \       /
  4    36
      /  \
    23    41
      \
       33
```

Note this is not a **balanced** binary search tree. A BST will simply create first a node `12` (first element you provide). And `12` will remain the root. All elements less than are sorted left (and start growing their own roots etc.)